# ElasTest Jenkins Plugin does not send test logs

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, elastest

Currently I am evaluating ElasTest. I also try the Jenkins Plguin, but the console output is not sent to ElasTest.

I have tried the example code snippet:

```
 elastest(surefireReportsPattern: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml', project: 'Jenkins Examples') {
            stage ('Executing Test') {
                echo 'Set up test environment'
                mvnHome =  tool 'maven-3.3.9'
                echo 'Cloning repository'
                git 'https://github.com/elastest/demo-projects'
                echo 'Run test'
                sh "cd ./unit/junit5-unit-test;'${mvnHome}/bin/mvn' -B -DforkCount=0 test"
                step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'])
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to know a few things:

- Which version of ElasTest you are using and where you are deploying it.
- Are you using your own Jenkins instance or the Jenkins instance integrated into ElasTest?

If you are using a Jenkins instance of your own, make sure that Jenkins can communicate with ElasTest and configure the plugin correctly. If ElasTest is on a server, open the necessary ports as indicated in the documentation: https://elastest.io/docs/deploying/ubuntu/

You can find more information on how to use the ElasTest plugin here: https://elastest.io/docs/tutorials/e2e-testing/